# Transforming equation with $e$ in order to find $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this task comes from electrotechnics.

How can I modify this equation in order to find $x$?
I need to have the equation in such form:

$x = \text{...something...}$

Here is the equation:
$$\exp\left(-\frac{a}{\frac{1}{2}bx}\right) = \frac{2c-d}{d}$$
(this is e to the power of $-\frac{a}{\frac{1}{2}bx}$, looks confusing).

Thank you.

Comment: Take the natural log of both sides. Cross multiply and it's a linear equation in $x$.

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty with this problem? Is just that it "looks confusing"? This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Well what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides gives:
$$\frac{-2a}{bx} = \ln(\frac{2c-d}{d})$$
Then divide both sides by $\ln(\frac{2c-d}{d})$ and multiply both sides by $x$ to obtain:
$$x = \frac{-2a}{b\ln(\frac{2c-d}{d})}$$

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \ln x gives $\ln x$ compared to ln x which gives $ln x$

Comment: Thanks Ross! Very helpful.